# arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: fatal error: -soname: must take a non-empty argument

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I am cross compiling gdcm with cmake android it goes till end of compilation but at last I get following error. how do you guys set -soname in cmake-gui or cmake while compiling libraries so that we can avoid below kind of error.

```
/opt/android/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-    androideabi/bin/ld: fatal error: -soname: must take a non-empty argument
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/likewise-open/SLKTECHLABS/kirtan.patel/Desktop/GDCM/GDCMSource/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgdcmjni.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Wrapping/Java/CMakeFiles/gdcmjni.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/kirtan.patel/Desktop/GDCM/GDCMSource/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageWriter.h:36: Warning 822: Covariant return     types not supported in Java. Proxy method will return gdcm::Pixmap const &.
/home/kirtan.patel/Desktop/GDCM/GDCMSource/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageCodec.h:45: Warning 473: Returning a     pointer or reference in a director method is not recommended.
```

Comment: you need to send the output of `make VERBOSE=1` because your output only contains warnings (not errors)

Comment: What version of cmake are you using? I had the same error with another product. Turns out that cmake 3.2.3 was the faulty part - I downgraded to 3.0.2 and the error was gone then.

Answer (score 9):

As [Romanski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691117/romanski) pointed out CMake versions 3.2 and 3.0 have different behaviour because of difference in `UseSWIG.cmake` files. In 3.2 `NO_SONAME` property [enabled](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14815) by [default](http://www.cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=f26147b8) looks like it raises conflict in android build producing invalid linking option `-Wl,-soname,` with empty TARGET_SONAME.

There are two ways to fix build with 3.2 version

1. `string(REPLACE "<CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SONAME_CXX_FLAG><TARGET_SONAME>" "" CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE "${CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE}")` eliminates broken linking option at all
2. `set_target_properties(${MY_TARGET} PROPERTIES NO_SONAME OFF)` fix broken linking option with correct so-name.